# What is the purpose of "Libvirt qemu" user?

Tags: 16.04, virtualization, qemu

What is the purpose of "Libvirt qemu" user that is created as non system user when installing some virtualisation package ?

Which package did that exactly ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's created by `libvirt-bin`:

```
$ grep libvirt-qemu /var/lib/dpkg/info/*.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libvirt-bin.postinst:# Allocated UID and GID for libvirt-qemu
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libvirt-bin.postinst:    if ! getent passwd libvirt-qemu >/dev/null; then
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libvirt-bin.postinst:            libvirt-qemu
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libvirt-bin.postinst:                chown libvirt-qemu:kvm "${dir}"
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libvirt-bin.postinst:    chown libvirt-qemu:kvm /var/lib/libvirt/qemu/channel/target
```

And it's a security measure. With services like web servers, mail servers, hypervisors, etc., the service should drop privileges and run as an unprivileged user instead of remaining as `root` after it has done any necessary initialization. This way, if the service is compromised, the attacker doesn't gain unrestricted root access. For [libvirt in particular](https://libvirt.org/drvqemu.html):

> If QEMU virtual machines from the "system" instance are being run as
>   non-root, there will be greater restrictions on what host resources
>   the QEMU process will be able to access.

Comment: Clear answer, documentation quote and link to it, wonderful!